# Point of sale callback not being called

Tags: square-connect, square

I am implementing the Point of Sale mobile web setup as described here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/setup-web

My app is redirecting to the POS app successfully.  If I close the POS app, my app redirects to the callback with an error as expected.  However, if the transaction is successful, the POS app remains open and does not redirect back to my callback for success handling.

Is there a way to automatically execute the callback upon successful completion of a transaction?  I can't rely on my users to do this and if they don't my app doesn't get notice of the successful transaction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you'll need to use *l.com.squareup.pos.AUTO_RETURN_TIMEOUT_MS=3200* to set auto_return for the Point of Sale Web API to switch back to your app automatically after the transaction completes.

For iOS, if you set the auto_return option to **true** the Square Point of Sale automatically switches back to your app following a short timeout after the transaction completes.

Comment: Kaled,  thanks for the response.  My URL uses S.com.squareup . . . for the constants and when I use "I" instead of "S" it doesn't go to the app.  That said (using S instead of I), this constant did not have the desired effect and the square app stays running indefinitely after processing.  I tried "AUTO_RETURN_TIMEOUT_MAX_MILLIS" as well based on documentation at https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/point-of-sale/android/constant-values.html but no joy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it should be a lowercase "L" instead of an uppercase "i".